# Is there an easy way to replace an url parameter in a referer in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, pcre, url-parameters

I am trying to update a parameter in my referer url:

```
$referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
```

For example, `$referer` is an url whith two parameter:

```
string(96) "http://<my_url>/web/app_dev.php/urlpart/?param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

I'd like to easyly replace `param1=value1` by `param1=updatedvalue1` for example with another one.

I know we can do this with `twig` with the current request url:

```
{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'),
   app.request.query.all|merge({'sort': 'address'})) }}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing in a Symfony 2 controller to update the referer?

I have found a solution with `preg_replace` function in `PHP`, I hope there is a better way to do it seems ugly, I am trying to find a better solution, any help will be apprecied!

```
$referer = preg_replace('/([?&])(param1)=\w+(&|$)/', '', $referer);
$referer = preg_replace('/(param2)=\w+(&|$)/', '', $referer);
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
$oldReferer = 'http://<my_url>/web/app_dev.php/urlpart/?param1=value1&param2=value2';
$newReferer = Request::create($oldReferer, 'GET', array('param1' => 'updatedvalue1'))->getUri();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want!